# Oracle SQL add uniform random numbers to column

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to create a new column based on an existing column plus some uniform random numbers.

**Data**

```
-- borrowed from https://stackoverflow.com/q/7745609/808921

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `docs` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `rev` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `content` float unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`rev`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `docs` (`id`, `rev`, `content`) VALUES
  ('1', '1', '1.24546'),
  ('2', '1', '1.245546546'),
  ('1', '2', '1.25654546'),
  ('1', '3', '1.2421323546');
```

Based on the OracleSQL documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_random.htm#ARPLS67507), I tried:

```
SELECT id, rev, content,
  content + DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE AS content2
FROM docs
```

There obviously is no "expected output" here, given the randomness, but I hope the schema + code are sufficiently clear to demonstrate what I am trying to achieve

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT id, rev, content,
  content + DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1,10) AS content2
FROM docs
```

Comment: This throws `ORA-00904: "DMBS_RADNOM"."VALUE": invalid identifier`

Comment: Probably because there's no DBMS_RA**DN**OM, but DBMS_RA**ND**OM.

Comment: This could be due to Insufficient user priviledges. Don't have access to the dbms_random package.
..................You need to GRANT EXECUTE to your schema. Login as your SYS user and run the following, replacing 'your-schema-name' with the Oracle user who you wish to allow run DBMS_RANDOM.

GRANT EXECUTE ON DBMS_RANDOM TO your-schema-name;

Comment: @Littlefoot that was a typo. The problem still exists.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the start value and end value as the parameters in the dbms_random function.

```
SELECT id, rev, content,
  content + DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, 20) AS content2  -- 1 - Start value, 20 - End value
FROM docs;
```

But not sure why you wanted to select random numbers and add it to your original value. If that is your requirement, above is the query

Comment: This throws `ORA-00904: "DMBS_RANDOM"."VALUE": invalid identifier`

Comment: Probably because there's no DBMS_RA**DN**OM, but DBMS_RA**ND**OM.

Comment: Your function name is incorrect. It should be `DBMS_RANDOM` and not `DMBS_RADNOM`

Comment: Thanks, but that wasn't the issue. Just a typo; the error is thrown in a virtual machine from which I cannot copy and paste error messages.